# Obtener todos los indices de un mismo elemento

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo dos listas `listA = [0, 4, 1, 3, 2]` y `listB = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]` lo que quiero es obtener todas aquellos indices en donde el elemento de `listA` aparezca en `listB` o sea que como resultado tendría `listR = [0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6]` ya intente haciendo con un `for`pero obviamente tarda mucho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un método eficiente puede ser construir antes un diccionario en el que las claves sean los números observados en B, y los valores sean listas con los índices dentro de B en que aparecen.

Este diccionario es fácil de construir:

```
from collections import defaultdict

listB = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
dic = defaultdict(list)
for indice, elemento in enumerate(listB):
  dic[elemento].append(indice)
```

Cuando este bucle termina, `dic` contiene el siguiente diccionario:

```
{0: [0, 1],
 1: [2, 3],
 2: [4, 5, 6],
 3: [7, 8, 9],
 4: [10, 11, 12]}
```

donde se ve por ejemplo, que el dato `3` apareció en los índices `[7,8,9]`.

A partir de este diccionario es fácil construir la lista que pides, simplemente recorriendo A y añadiendo a la lista resultado las listas que salen del diccionario, según el valor del elemento de A:

```
listA = [0, 4, 1, 3, 2]
r = []
for elemento in listA:
  r.extend(dic[elemento])
```

Al terminar, `r` tiene la lista que buscabas:

```
[0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6]
```

Observa que si al recorrer A aparece algún dato que no estaba en B, la línea `dic[elemento]` causará un error al no haber en el diccionario esa clave. Puedes arreglarlo fácilmente si en vez de `dic[elemento]` pones `dic.get(elemento, [-1])`, por ejemplo, para que te de `-1` para los casos en que no lo encuentre (o `[None]`, o el valor que quieras poner)

Comment: Muchas gracias.